# Can't do regex matching on object using an NSPredicate on a UITextField

Tags: swift, regex, email-validation

Checking email regEx giving error:

> Can't do regex matching on object error

in an extension to UITextField.

```
let emailRegEx : String = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"
let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
let e = emailTest.evaluate(with: self)
```

Comment: What is `self`?

Comment: @Carpsen90 It's a `UITextField`.

Comment: `let e = emailTest.evaluate(with: self.text!)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is a `UITextField`. So you want `self.text!` so the predicate is run against the text of the text field.

```
let e = emailTest.evaluate(with: self.text!)
```

And yes, it's safe to force-unwrap the `text` property of a `UITextField`.